# NSString+EncodeURIComponent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.3

Below code is NON ARC code, can some one tell me how can i convert it to ARC one, it has a memory leak when i am using it, to encode url.

```
#import "NSString+EncodeURIComponent.h"

@implementation NSString (EncodeURIComponent)

+ (NSString*)stringEncodeURIComponent:(NSString *)string {
    return [((NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) autorelease];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: ARC doesn't allow the `autorelease` keyword. Doesn't the compiler tell you that? You should try compiling and see what the compiler says.

Comment: when i turn on ARC it says cast of objective c pointer type 'CFStringRef' to Objective c pointer type 'NSString' requires bridged cast. its not just about autorelease.

Comment: Just removing `autorelease` will cause this to leak memory. You still have to balance the `Create` with a `CFRelease()`. To do that while also converting to ARC, you use `CFBridgingRelease()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            (__bridge CFStringRef)string,
                                            NULL,
                                            CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

This does the followng:

- Remove the `autorelease`
- Pass the Core Foundation object to ARC using `CFBridgingRelease()`. This balances the `Create`. In principle (though not implementation), Core Foundation performs a `CFRelease()` and ARC performs an `objc_retain()`.
- Add a `_bridge` case to your use of `string`. This tells the compiler that you are not transferring ownership between ARC and Core Foundation. You just want Core Foundation to use an ARC variable.
- Use `CFSTR()` to create a constant Core Foundation string. This is more convenient than creating a constant `NSString` and then bridge casting it to Core Foundation.

See "Managing Toll-Free Bridging" in the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).